# .docx issue in Apache servers

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mime

What I have to write to the .htaccess file so that the visitors will be able to download .docx files?

Comment: So much more information required.  Like why you think they can't download them now.

Comment: I have added
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document docx
to the .htaccess file, didn't worked
and
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document docx
to the mime.types under etc/ and etc/mydomain.com, did't worked.

Comment: It works by this way:
Run socalledoriginal.docx file as php (AddType application/x-httpd-php .docx)

<?php
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="socalledoriginal.docx" ');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('cv/original.docx');
?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a browser configuration problem. Make sure your browser is configured to download files of the appropriate content type rather than trying to display them.

Also, you could try adding the `Content-Disposition` header, which can be done with the `Header` directive in Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header  Here's one explanation of how to use the header: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519

Answer (score 2):

Are your docx files trying to be run as zip files from the client?  Since Office2007 files are essentially just xml files zipped together, Unix treats them like regular zip files, due to their magic numbers.  And thus Apache sends the wrong MIME type headers.

A rather succinct answer for this can be found in another serverfault question: [Why are docx, xlsx, pptx downloading from webserver as zip files?](https://serverfault.com/questions/19060/why-are-docx-xlsx-pptx-downloading-from-webserver-as-zip-files)

Comment: No, they are not run as a zip file but as a text file.

Comment: I have already tried the method in the link, it didn't helped.

Answer (score 1):

This is an IE problem, but easy to solve in the .htaccess:

```
 <FilesMatch "\.(?i:docm|docx|xlsx|xlsm|xlsb|pptx|pptm|ppsx)$">
  Header set Pragma private
</FilesMatch>
```

Make sure you don't use SSL (https) or iE gives an error