# Forcing apache to send correct Content-Type for docx files

Tags: apache-2.2, mime

This seems to be an old problem:  Users retrieving docx files from apache are receiving them with a Content-Type header which claims they're zip archives.

After a good deal of searching for solutions I have:

- Added `AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document docx` to my `mod_mime` config, as suggested in one of the top answers to [Why are docx, xlsx, pptx downloading from webserver as zip files?](https://serverfault.com/questions/19060/why-are-docx-xlsx-pptx-downloading-from-webserver-as-zip-files)
- Verified that `/etc/mime.types` contains `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document  docx` (I didn't add it, it was already there), as suggested by the other top answer to that question
- Added multiple directives to `/etc/magic`, which have had the net effect that `file` now recognizes docx correctly instead of calling it "Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract"

Despite all these things, apache continues to send docx files with a `Content-Type: application/zip; charset=UTF-8` header.

The running apache is version `Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)` under Debian squeeze.

What else might I need to do to get docx to be sent with the correct Content-Type?

Answer (score -1):

Problem identified and resolved.  The files in question were being downloaded via a custom application which sets its own Content-Type headers.